# Need help on opening/creating a text file

Tags: python

I need help on the opening up the text file.  For some reason it does not seem to be working correctly, and I was wondering if someone could point out any errors and tell me how to solve them.  Thanks.

```
import time
import operator
import random

username=input("What is your name?")

usersClass = input("Which class are you in, 1, 2 or 3?")
print ("Welcome {} to the Math quiz, hope you have fun lets begin".format(username))

start = time.time()

def askquestion():
  score = 0
  opslist = {operator.add: "+", operator.sub: "-", operator.mul: "x"}
  num1,num2 = random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10)    
  ops = random.choice(list(opslist.keys()))                       
  ActualAnswer = (ops(num1,num2))                               
  score = 0
  print(num1,opslist[ops],num2)            
  userAns = (int(input("Answer the above")))
  if userAns == ActualAnswer:   
    print("Awesome, that's correct")
    return 1
  else:
    print("Incorrect sorry")
    score = score - 0
  return 0

totalScore = 0
for i in range (10):
  totalScore += askquestion()  

print ("Well done, you have completed the quiz")

print("your final score was " + str(totalScore))
if totalScore > 9:
    print("Great work! You got top marks!")
elif totalScore > 7:
   print("Good, try harder next time and you might get full marks!")
elif totalScore > 5:
    print("You did alright")
elif totalScore > 4:
    print("Are you not motivated.. c'mon")
else:
    print("Hmmm..dissapointing, however know you know what you need to work on")

end = time.time()
etime = end - start
timeTaken = round(etime)

if usersClass == 1:
    with open("class1.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("{}:Scored {} in {} seconds".format(username,totalScore,timeTaken))

elif usersClass == 2:
    with open("class2.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("{}:Scored {} in {} seconds".format(username,totalScore,timeTaken))

elif usersClass == 3:
    with open("class3.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("{}:Scored {} in {} seconds".format(username,totalScore,timeTaken))
```

Comment: "Not working correctly" isn't helpful. What *is* happening and what errors do you get?

Comment: the last part of my code starting from if usersclass == 1: etc; i need it to open a file that would display the score of the user and time it took. Relating this to the start of the code i wonder if i have entered anything wrong as on python the last section does not seem to be showing up/opening the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>So it looks like there a couple of things you may need to change. You should probably use raw_input to capture input from the user.</strike>

Your if statements for usersClass likely aren't triggering because they are looking for an int rather than the string of the number that gets passed in the input.

You can either turn those inputs into ints: usersClass = int(usersClass) OR you can just add quotes around the ints in your if statements: if usersClass == "1":

Also, looks like there is an unintentional indent in your first if statement.

EDIT: Just realized you are likely using Python3.x, no need to change input to raw_input as it doesn't exist in Python3...my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assure the value of `usersClass` doesn't get less than 1 or greater than 3. You never did it, that's why if you enter some number that doesn't meet these conditions the file wouldn't be opened or created.

I didn't understand the meaning of `score = score - 0` above the last line of `askquestion`. What does it mean? If you don't want to change the value of a variable, don't do it.